# How can I correct my logout function on React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've been attempting to fix this for some time and I keep running into issues. After spending over a week trying to fix the issue, I feel as though I'm progressing but still not where I want to be. My goal is to use the 'SignOutBtn' button in the Setting Page, to logout from the app. My approach to the solution was to change the app status 'loggedIn: true' in App.JS to 'loggedIn: false'. Can someone please take the time to look over my code and help me resolve the issue?

App Page

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loaded: true,
      loggedIn: true,
    }
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this)
  }

  logout() {
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: false,
    })
    
  }

  render() {
    const { loggedIn, loaded } = this.state;
    if (!loaded) {
      useEffect(() => {
        createInstallation = async () => {
          const  Installation = Parse.Object.extend(Parse.Installation);
          const  installation = new  Installation();
            
          installation.set('deviceType', Platform.OS);
          await  installation.save();
        };
        
        createInstallation();
      }, []);
      return (
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.container}>Loading...</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }

    if (!loggedIn) {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator initailRouteName="LoginScreen">
            <Stack.Screen
              name="LogIn"
              component={LoginScreen}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }

    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initailRouteName="Main">
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Main"
            component={MainScreen}
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="Explore" component={ExploreScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Setting" 
            component={SettingScreen} 
            logout = {this.logout} 
          
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

Setting Page:

```
export default class Setting extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.signOut =  this.signOut.bind(this);
  }

  signOut(){
    this.props.logout;
    console.log("onPress");
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.SettingsTitle}>Settings page</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.SignOutBtn}
            onPress={() => this.signOut() }
          >
          <Text style={styles.SignOutText}>Sign Out</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#212121",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  SettingsTitle: {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: "#EEEEEE",
    marginBottom: 300,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  SignOutText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: "#EEEEEE",
  },
  SignOutBtn: {
    width: "125%",
    backgroundColor: "#F2A950",
    borderRadius: 25,
    height: 40,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginTop: 100,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
});
```

Any advice and tips to avoid making mistakes like this in the future would be really appreciative!

Answer (score 0):

i'm thinking of two ways of authentication

1. **use [AsyncStorage](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/) and SplashScreen**

make the splashscreen as a default screen in the navigator.

then make simple code like this =>

**splashScreen.js**

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {ActivityIndicator, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';

const index = () => {
  const nav = useNavigation();
  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('profile').then((data) => {
      if (data) {
        nav.replace('home');
      } else {
        nav.replace('login');
      }
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <ActivityIndicator size="large" animating />
    </View>
  );
};
export default index;
```

and create one function for logout and login

```
const login = (email, password) => {
  AsyncStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify({email, password}));
  nav.replace('splashScreen');
};
const logout = () => {
  AsyncStorage.removeItem('profile');
  nav.replace('splashScreen');
};
```

2. **use Global State ([Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started))**

Spoiler : its hard for me at least, but i do understand the basic.

forget about the splashscreen you can put global state in your navigation

example of redux usage =>

your navigation will look like this

```
const isLogin = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isLogin); 
...
 <Stack.Navigator initailRouteName="Main">
    {isLogin?(
      //put all login screen here
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Main"
        component={MainScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />):(
       <Stack.Screen
          name="LogIn"
          component={LoginScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
    )
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

the redux login and logout function look like this

```
const login ()=>{
dispatch(authAction({email:"email@email.com",password:"password",isLogin:true}));
//no need to navigate because u are already using a global state in the navigation
}
const logout () =>{
dispatch(authAction({isLogin:false}))
}
```

good luck.
i personally love redux it is the best practice to have your app handled by a global state but asyncStorage is also important